# trigger performance over different cases

Tags: performance, sql-server-2005, triggers

I have a table that collects logs of every check_in. I want to pick 4 columns to later process them. I have placed a trigger on every insert and columns are copied. I am confused over which way to do it. For best PERFORMANCE. Below are some different ways I figured out.  Assuming my destination table is indexed.

```html
ALTER trigger GetCheckIn_HA_Transit

on tableXyz

 AFTER INSERT

as

declare @cardName nvarchar(max)
declare @checkIn datetime
declare @direction varchar(30)
declare @terminal varchar(30)

select 

@direction = str_direction, 
@terminal = TERMINAL,
@cardName = card_number,
@checkIn = transit_date 

from tableXyz 

GO    

INSERT INTO logs(direction,terminal,cardName,checkIn)

VALUES

(@direction,@terminal,@cardName,@checkIn)

end
```

Another way i found was without declaration

```html
ALTER trigger GetCheckIn_HA_Transit

on tableXyz

 AFTER INSERT

as

GO

INSERT INTO 
logs(direction,terminal,cardName,checkIn)

SELECT(STR_DIRECTION,TERMINAL,card_number,transit_date)FROM tableXyz
```

And is copying data from one table to another table is better in terms of performance than to copy from one database table to another database table over same server ??

Assuming every second we have an insert that will trigger our Trigger.